# Rendering data from WordPress REST API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, haml

I have a WordPress site and a Rails site hosted on separate servers. I need to pull information from some custom post types on the WordPress site and display them on the Rails app. At a minimum, I would like to display all the post titles (hyper-linked)  – there's no writing to WordPress needed.

I'm not well-versed in Ruby on Rails or HAML – I'm basically just a WordPress/PHP developer – so I'm at a loss as to how to begin. I'm thinking the best way is to pull data from WordPress using the WP REST API (http://v2.wp-api.org) plugin, but I don't know how to go about rendering data from an API in RoR/HAML. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Yep exposing an API on the WordPress side would be a good option, you're on the right lines.

In this situation you could do is start by creating a [controller, route and view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) ([hopefully some tests too](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)) then within the controller you can request the data from the WordPress API. For this you will need a HTTP client, [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) is part of the Ruby stdlib or alternatively something like [faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) which offers a little more flexibility. From here you can pass the response data into an object that you can use in your HAML views as required. You don't want to be assigning the JSON to an instance variable in your controller and accessing it as a Hash in the view, create a class that [parses](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) the response and provides some methods to allow you to access the data using method calls.

This would get you going in terms of a basic implementation but once you get the basics working it may be worth doing a little refactoring. For example what you would have now is a small wrapper around the API and this could be a logic extraction from your controller. The advantage being that the controller code becomes easier to understand and also should you wish to use the wrapper somewhere else within your application that becomes much simpler.

Edit: You could also use a REST ORM like [her](https://github.com/remiprev/her)